Constrained random sampling from partitioned sets with quotas
Let $D$ be a finite set, $\mathcal{P} = \{D_{i,j}\}_{(i,j) \in I \times J}$ a partition of $D$, $N: J \to \mathbb{N}$ a quota function, and $k \in \mathbb{N}^+$. A subset $F \subseteq D$ is considered feasible if $|F \cap D_{i,j}| \le k$ for all $(i,j) \in I \times J$ and $\left| F \cap \bigcup_{i \in I} D_{i,j} \right| \ge N(j)$ for all $j \in J$.
Based on this, are there any conditions on the tuple $(D, \mathcal{P}, N, k)$ that guarantee the existence of a feasible set $F$? When a feasible set $F$ exists, under what circumstances is it unique up to relabeling within each $D_{i,j}$?
Some initial conjectures:

A feasible sample $F$ exists if and only if for every $J' \subseteq J$,
$$\left| \bigcup_{j \in J'} \bigcup_{i \in I} D_{i,j} \right| \ge \sum_{j \in J'} N(j),$$
and
$$\left| \bigcup_{i \in I} D_{i,j} \right| \ge N(j) \text{ for all } j \in J.$$

Uniqueness (up to relabeling) of a feasible sample $F$ occurs precisely when the above inequalities are tight for certain critical subsets of $J$, and the structure of $\mathcal{P}$ restricts the choice of elements within each $D_{i,j}$ to meet the quotas.


Do these seem like valid conjectures and are there any relate results in the literature?
The motivation for this problem is based on the common need to conduct random sampling from a dataset partitioned into subpopulations, while adhering to constraints on the representation of each subpopulation and fulfilling quotas for specific categories. This is usually helpful for building representative machine learning model (I.e since the data is not skewed or biased the model will be “good” in some sense).
